# Is there any way to prefetch or cache audio in React Native?

Tags: android, react-native, caching, audio

Is there any method to prefetch audio in React Native or is there any library that allows me to do so  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With lack of information, I believe you are asking if you can download audio with react native? 
You can use something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/rn-fetch-blob 
This will allow you to save a stream to phone storage, give you a path to the file on the phone, then you can save that to reuse at a later time.

An example from their docs.

```
RNFetchBlob.config({
// add this option that makes response data to be stored as a file,
// this is much more performant.
fileCache : true,
})
.fetch('GET', 'http://www.example.com/file/example.zip', {
  //some headers ..
})
.then((res) => {
  // the temp file path
  console.log('The file saved to ', res.path())
})
```